# Changing mock up into skin in DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

Friends I am starting to build one site using DotNetNuke. I am completely beginner in the DotNetNuke. I have mock up of site in html and i need to create skin and layout in DotNetNuke as in mock up. I tried to include the files in skin folder of DotNetNuke but it doesn't work.

And i am stuck with this. So, If anyone suggest me how can i change my mock up into the skin of my site in DotNetNuke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by looking at the Basic DotNetNuke Skinning webinar I recorded last year, it will give you an intro to Skinning for the platform.

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Training/Basic-Skinning.aspx

You could also take a look at http://multifunction.codeplex.com for an example skin